# IOS: Run Rapidminer as admin

Tags: ios, macos, terminal, admin, rapidminer

I need to run RapidMiner as an admin on IOS.
How do I start it as admin?
I tried `sudo /Applications/RapidMiner\ Studio.app`, but it didn't work.

The error: `sudo: /Applications/RapidMiner Studio.app: command not found`

The question is: How can I start RapidMiner from the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For most apps (aside from Rapidminer), the actual binary launchable via the terminal is hidden in the application bundle.

It looks like Rapidminer is quite a bit different.

You should be able to do something like:

`RapidMiner Studio.app\Contents\Resources\RapidMiner-Studio-App.sh`

Comment: Doesn't work. In Contents/MacOS/ I only have RapidMiner Studio Marketplace Utility.

Comment: Hi, you can just download the platform independed version to have the .sh available.

Comment: or use the launcher script in Contents/Resources/

Comment: The .sh file is found in RapidMiner Studio.app\Contents\Resources\RapidMiner-Studio-App.sh

Comment: @Marco Thanks, it worked!